# Rescaling y axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing an R script that reads columns from a table and plots them using ggplot2. It does this fine, but the plot looks like this

[image: dFig]

As you can see, the y-axis is not legible, and while this questions has been brought up before, none of the other suggestions seems to work here. My code includes

```
scaledfig <- function(x) sprintf("%.25f", x)
as.numeric(motionTable$abs_disp)
as.numeric(motionTable$rel_disp)

dFig <- ggplot(motionTable, aes(x = volNum, y = Displacement (mm), color = Displacement))
dFig <- dFig + geom_line(aes(y = motionTable$abs_disp, col = "Absolute", group = "Absolute"))
dFig <- dFig + geom_line (aes(y = motionTable$rel_disp, col = "Relative", group = "Relative"))
dFig <- dFig + geom_point(aes(y = motionTable$abs_disp, col = "Absolute"))
dFig <- dFig + geom_point (aes(y = motionTable$rel_disp, col = "Relative"))
dFig <- dFig + labs (x = "Volume Number", y = "Displacement (mm)", title = "Absolute and Relative Displacements")
dFig <- dFig + labs(title = paste("Subject", i))
dFig + scale_y_continuous(labels = scaledFig)
#dFig + scale_y_continuous(name = "Displacement (mm)", breaks = seq(0.0,2.0,0.25))
#dFig + scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=10)
```

`dput(head(motionTable, 10))` outputs

```
structure(list(abs_disp = c("0", "0.3598496043", "0.3367404595", 
"0.5612950955", "0.5926686078", "0.6773828289", "0.7191384228", 
"1.060469172", "0.6591592446", "0.6038018978"), rel_disp = c("0", 
"0.3598496043", "0.2923699689", "0.4280773273", "0.1091926443", 
"0.1313908402", "0.1313493555", "1.560717967", "0.484082429", 
"0.1986202777"), tranX = c("0", "-0.0785146579", "-0.07608680893", 
"-0.07561987897", "-0.04065532835", "-0.06546745333", "-0.07439172898", 
"-0.2786683609", "-0.1795976768", "-0.18284101"), tranY = c("0", 
"0.1227999718", "-0.1630289336", "0.1584651318", "0.08877167101", 
"0.1767835047", "0.1202046746", "-0.1370894171", "-0.01578245448", 
"-0.1090108712"), tranZ = c("0", "-0.2684659095", "-0.2694665248", 
"-0.5203157126", "-0.5747761354", "-0.6256571446", "-0.6953128941", 
"0.7029104699", "0.2864873026", "0.1099864166"), rotX = c("0", 
"-0.003156857798", "-0.000892180542", "0.0004263653827", "0.001874236856", 
"0.00283550215", "0.003425042611", "0.01218409184", "0.009841443971", 
"0.01025226619"), rotY = c("-0", "0.000321621832", "-2.743286495e-05", 
"0.001403134549", "0.00132931408", "0.002377087483", "0.0002640777093", 
"0.002981501399", "0.00105366786", "0.001413969789"), rotZ = c("0", 
"0.0002346710389", "0.0001198071914", "0.001037030946", "0.001400115783", 
"0.001185192959", "0.001652514678", "5.723586582e-05", "0.001358391484", 
"0.001774424105"), fill = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000026a1ef0>)
```

I have tried all of the above and still a weird y axis. What am I missing?

Comment: Without seeing a sample of your data this is just a guess.  I assume the data in not numeric given since you have included this line: `as.numeric(motionTable$rel_disp)` and are not reassigning the result to the original data.

Comment: can you post the results of `dput(head(motionTable, 10))`

Comment: added the dput output to the post

Comment: check `class(d$abs_disp)` you have non-numeric values. Also first row is weirdly filled with zeros.

Comment: @PoGibas this is a motion report during an MRI scan, the first line is the start and is expected to be 0

Comment: The data sample does in fact show all of the columns being character objects and not numeric.  You have to convert these columns to numeric before calling the ggplot function.

Comment: @Dave2e You're right, setting them to numeric instead fixed it. Thank you!